# Proof of an equation about determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Please prove an equation about a determinant: (Sorry, I cannot figure any solution)

$$\text{det}(I+ab^T)=1+a^Tb$$

Comment: Are you assuming $a$ and $b$ are both $n \times 1$ vectors?

Comment: cptn. obvious does agree.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry to forget this notation.

Comment: @Max I'll never assume something about a problem if it wasn't explicitly stated.  If it seemed obvious to you, congratulations!  I'm pleased for you.

Comment: $ab^t$ has one eigenvalue equal to $b^ta$ and the others 0. So $ab^t+I$ has one eigenvalue equal to $b^ta+1$ and the others 1.

Answer (score 2):

$ I+ab^T $ is the sum between the identity matrix and a matrix with rank $\leq 1$. Since the identity matrix commutes with every matrix, the only eigenvalue of $I$ is $1$ and the only (possibly) non-zero eigenvalue of $ab^T$ is $a^T b$, the eigenvalues of $I+ ab^T$ are $1+ a^T b$ and $1$. The determinant is just the product of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply an application of [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem).

Comment: Can you give more details on this? What do you choose for $A$, $B$ respectivley in Sylvesters theorem? (I don't instantly see the solution, so I assume others might think the same.)

Comment: @Max there are exactly two candidates here: $a$ and $b^T$. One should be chosen for $A$, and the other chosen for $B$.

Comment: yes of course... the determnant of a real is that very real xD